# $\alpha$ is a root $\implies -\alpha$ is a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

I want to prove:

> $\alpha\in \mathfrak{h}^*$ be a root of $\frak g$, $\implies$ so is $-\alpha$.

---

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ have basis $\{h_1,\cdots,h_r\}$

I am not really sure how to prove this, I mean $\alpha$ being a root, means that $e_\alpha \in \frak g \setminus h$ have $ad_{h_i}(e_\alpha) = \alpha_i e_\alpha$ and we take the eigenvalues $\alpha_i$ and form the root:

$$(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r)$$

So I need to prove that:

$$(-\alpha_1,\cdots,-\alpha_r)$$

is a root, which feels like I need to show that $e_{-\alpha}$ is a vector in $\frak g\backslash h$, which I don't know how to really 'show'.

---

Is this as simple as: $ad_{h_i}(-e_\alpha)=[h_i,-e_\alpha]=-[h_i,e_\alpha]=-\alpha_i e_\alpha$ for each $h_i$, $i\in \{1,\cdots,r\}$:

$$(-\alpha_1,\cdots,-\alpha_r)$$

As desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show it using the fact that:

If $\alpha,\beta \in \Delta,\ \alpha+\beta\neq 0$ then $K(e_\alpha,e_\beta)=0$

where $\Delta$ are the roots and $K$ the killing form.

Comment: This isn't an answer for me sorry. I know of this, and can't see how it yields the result. Here $\alpha+\beta$ does equal $0$, where $\beta=-\alpha$.

Comment: You know that the killing form is non-degenerate so for each non zero $e_\alpha$ it exist $e_b$ s.t $K(e_\alpha,e_b)\neq 0$ but from the proposition I show you, this is only possible if $b=-\alpha$

Comment: So since the killing form is non degenerate, we know that $\forall \alpha, \exists \beta : k(e_\alpha,e_\beta)\ne 0$, since $\alpha+\beta \ne 0 \implies k(e_\alpha,e_\beta)=0$ we need some $\alpha + \beta = 0$ for it to be non degenerate, hence $\alpha = -\beta$.

Okay that makes sense, thanks!